# NSXMLParser Parser Error With G1 Only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I have a simple xml doc.. it is well formed and passes correctly when using:

xmlData = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL ];

Over WiFi or 3G.

However I receive a  NSXMLParserPrematureDocumentEndError  when using G1.

I'm thinking the slower connection somehow cuts off the xml document after some time but can't find any help on the issue.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are not the only one to run against this problem. [Someone apparently solved this problem on Apple Support forums](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1658516).

Comment: The gist of the solution on the support forum is to download the data first into a string and then pass it into the parser once you've gotten the whole thing.